# Is it possible to have the original half of the mesh erased when using the Mirror Modifier?

Tags: modifiers, mirror-modifier

As per title, I see that the *Mirror Modifier* keeps the original mesh, and I couldn't find an option to erase it.

The *Flip* option does not seem to work.
[image]

Tried to enable/disable all those nice XYZ in any possible combination, but didn't work.

For now, the only solution seems to convert to mesh, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: to flip a mesh press S/(axis)/-1, or Ctrl M + axis. I'm not sure this is what you want though...

Comment: or just rotate by 180 degree on any axis you want....

Comment: flip does only work with bisect checked...here is the explanation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html

Comment: so in your case R Y 180 should work -> before, just delete your mirror modifier

Comment: Rotating a mesh by 180° won't mirror it though

Comment: Exactly: rotating is very different from flipping.  And I want to have it as modifier, I know how to flip mirror etc. as a model...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this sequence of modifiers ..

- The *Hook* is of all vertices to an Empty, scaled to -1 in the mirror axis, after binding.
- The *Solidify* is with 'Thickness' 0, no 'Rim', 'Flip' -ped normals
- The *Weld* gets rid of the shell created by the *Solidify*

[image]

The second 2 modifiers are just to restore outward-facing normals.

There's probably a better way.. Geometry Nodes can do it too, but I don't think you can flip normals, in those, yet?

[image]

Comment: Instructive answer, thank you! However for some reason it's not working lol.

Answer (score 3):

### Mirror + Mask

[image]

1. **Create two vertex groups** `all.R` and `all.L`, and assign all geometry to either (here I start with a right side so I assign all geometry to `all.R`).
2. **Add a Mirror Modifier**. By default, *Data > Vertex Groups* option is enabled, and so data from each vertex group with `.R` suffix will be moved to `.L` suffix counterpart for created geometry, vice-versa for `.L` -> `.R`. **Disable *Merge* so that no geometry is shared between vertex groups.**
3. **Add a Mask Modifier;** specify which side you want to display (in my example `all.L`).

Comment: See? I _told_ @PolyMad there was a better way! :D (You can tell I don't do much trad. rigging and skinning) I feel I should delete my answer, really...

Comment: @RobinBetts I think it's always nice to have alternatives.